# C# quiz game: right radiobutton label score

Tags: c#, radio-button, label

I'm making a quiz game project in a windows forms application in C# and trying to make it so that the right radiobutton click gives 1 score on label and 0 on wrong answer. There are 4 radiobuttons in a groupbox and one is a right answer. The problem I'm having with the code is that if I put one right answer in the first radiobutton and then continue onto the next groupboxes questions, it doesn't add the score so let's say the first 2 groupbox questions are both right, the first one it adds so the score is 1 and after clicking right on the next it just stays 1. What do I need to add to the code so it counts the answers right?

```cs
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                int score = 1;
                label1.Text = score.ToString();
                score = score += 1;
                score.ToString();
            }


 private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton5.Checked)
            {
                int score = 1;
                label1.Text = score.ToString();
                score = score += 1;
                score.ToString();
            }
```

The first radiobutton is the right answer for the first groupbox, and it adds 1 to the label. On the second radiobutton it should add 1 score to the label so the total score should be 2, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really get what you are trying to achieve, however you always initialize `score` as `1` within each function, then write it to the label and only after that add 1 to the score. The last `score.ToString();` doesn't really do anything. So of course the result of both functions is that the label will show `1`

Answer (score 0):

Define a new member variable outside the methods. Then you can access it from every method in this class. Also: += 1 already adds 1 to score, so you don't have to do score = score += 1.

```
private int _score = 0;

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            _score += 1;
            label1.Text = _score.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton5.Checked)
        {
            _score += 1;
            label1.Text = _score.ToString();
        }
     }
```

The next thing you should do, is probably think about to outsource the calculation and UI updating into new methods. E.G.:

```
private void AddToScore(int points)
{
    _score += points;
}
```

So you could say instead:

```
if (radioButton5.Checked)
{
    AddToScore(5); //Adds 5 points to score
    label1.Text = _score.ToString();
}
```